# Timing Out A Long Running cgo Function Call

Tags: go, timeout, cgo

I am currently working on a program which calls a long running function using a c library with `cgo`. I cannot edit the library to allow for timeouts using c. My only solution so far was to leave a zombie goroutine running

```
func Timeout(timeout time.Duration, runFunc func()) bool {
    var wg = new(sync.WaitGroup)
    c := make(chan interface{})
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer close(c)
        wg.Wait()
    }()
    go func() {
        runFunc()
        c <- nil
        wg.Done()
    }()
    select {
    case <-c:
        return false
    case <-time.After(timeout):
        return true
    }
}
```

with the long running function working but this is for a long-running server which can lead to massive memory leaks/wasted cpu cycles over time.

Comment: No, you cannot interrupt a blocking cgo call. You might want run the functions in a separate process that can be easily killed and cleaned up.

Comment: @JimB if you answer this question with that comment I'll choose it as the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two ways to interrupt a cgo function call.

1. Leave the goroutine running but stop waiting/blocking on it as demonstrated above
2. Put all of the logic behind the cgo call in a separate executable and call it within a subprocess.